# how to specify font for superscripts using ucharclasses with xelatex

Tags: xetex, superscripts, tamil, ucharclasses

Lohit Tamil Classical font that I am using with Xelatex does not have a glyph for superscript 4. (please see https://github.com/pravins/lohit/issues/68)

I have tried using ucharclasses for automatic switching to a different font for superscripts, but it is not working.

This is what I have in my preamble:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[Scale=1]
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Scale=1.05]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Scale=1,Script=Tamil,Language=Tamil]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Scale=1,Script=Tamil]{Lohit Tamil Classical}

\usepackage[Latin, Tamil, SuperscriptsandSubscripts]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{SuperscriptsandSubscripts}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionFrom{SuperscriptsandSubscripts}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionTo{Tamil}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Tamil}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Latin}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
  {\hyphenrules{sanskrit}\tamilfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Tamil}
  {\hyphenrules{sanskrit}\tamilfont}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
%
```

and here is a sample of text from the document.

```
\section{அத² ஷட³ஸ்த்ரிம்ஶ: படல:}

ஶ்ரீஆனந்த³பை⁴ரவீ உவாச
அத² காந்த ப்ரவக்ஷ்யாமி குண்ட³லீசேதனாதி³கம் ।
ஸஹஸ்ரநாமஸகலம் குண்ட³லின்யா: ப்ரியம் ஸுக²ம் ॥ 36-1॥

அஷ்டோத்தரம் மஹாபுண்யம் ஸாக்ஷாத் ஸித்³தி⁴ப்ரதா³யகம் ।
தவ ப்ரேமவஶேனைவ கத²யாமி ஶ்ருʼணுஷ்வ தத் ॥ 36-2॥
```

---

Edit:

Here is an MWE, please let me know how I can get it to display the 4 superscript. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,polyglossia,fontspec,etoolbox}
%
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[Scale=1]
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Scale=1.05]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Scale=1,Script=Tamil]{Lohit Tamil Classical}
%
\usepackage[Latin, Tamil]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{SuperscriptsandSubscripts}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionFrom{SuperscriptsandSubscripts}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionTo{Tamil}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Tamil}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Latin}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
  {\hyphenrules{tamil}\tamilfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Tamil}
  {\hyphenrules{tamil}\tamilfont}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
%
\begin{document}
\section{அத² ஷட³ஸ்த்ரிம்ஶ: படல:}

ஶ்ரீஆனந்த³பை⁴ரவீ உவாச
அத² காந்த ப்ரவக்ஷ்யாமி குண்ட³லீசேதனாதி³கம் ।
ஸஹஸ்ரநாமஸகலம் குண்ட³லின்யா: ப்ரியம் ஸுக²ம் ॥ 36-1॥

அஷ்டோத்தரம் மஹாபுண்யம் ஸாக்ஷாத் ஸித்³தி⁴ப்ரதா³யகம் ।
தவ ப்ரேமவஶேனைவ கத²யாமி ஶ்ருʼணுஷ்வ தத் ॥ 36-2॥

வினா யஜனயோகே³ன வினா த்⁴யானேன யத்ப²லம் ।
தத்ப²லம் லப⁴தே ஸத்³யோ வித்³யாயா: ஸுக்ருʼபா ப⁴வேத் ॥ 36-3॥
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is `SuperscriptsAndSubscripts` (note the uppercase A).

Here I use a Tamil font I have on my machine.

For the transitions to/from superscripts, it's better to go with `\begingroup\normalfont` and `\endgroup`, so this will work independently on the context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[Scale=1]
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Scale=1.05]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Scale=1,Script=Tamil,Language=Tamil]{InaiMathi}
%\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Scale=1,Script=Tamil]{Lohit Tamil Classical}

\usepackage[Latin, Tamil, SuperscriptsAndSubscripts]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{SuperscriptsAndSubscripts}{\begingroup\normalfont}
\setTransitionFrom{SuperscriptsAndSubscripts}{\endgroup}

\setTransitionTo{Tamil}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Tamil}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Latin}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
  {\hyphenrules{sanskrit}\tamilfont}
\setTransitionsFor{Tamil}
  {\hyphenrules{sanskrit}\tamilfont}
  {\hyphenrules{english}\normalfont}
%

\begin{document}

\section{அத² ஷட³ஸ்த்ரிம்ஶ: படல:}

ஶ்ரீஆனந்த³பை⁴ரவீ உவாச
அத² காந்த ப்ரவக்ஷ்யாமி குண்ட³லீசேதனாதி³கம் ।
ஸஹஸ்ரநாமஸகலம் குண்ட³லின்யா: ப்ரியம் ஸுக²ம் ॥ 36-1॥

அஷ்டோத்தரம் மஹாபுண்யம் ஸாக்ஷாத் ஸித்³தி⁴ப்ரதா³யகம் ।
தவ ப்ரேமவஶேனைவ கத²யாமி ஶ்ருʼணுஷ்வ தத் ॥ 36-2॥

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The above works fine with article. For memoir, I had to remove the \begingroup and \endgroup - as it was causing the error 'extra \endgroup'

Comment: @shreeshrii I have no error if I change `article` into `memoir`

Comment: In my document along with memoir class, I have a lot of other commands in the preamble. Maybe, there was a conflict with one of those.